# Linear transformation for noisy data in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-transform

I have a dataset that you see below.  The data is pretty noisy, but there is a clear linear trend that goes up and to the right.  I'd like to transform the data with y = m * x to make the lines horizontal.  Essentially, I'd like to do a regression on the orange lines to pull out the slope, but I don't know how to extract the different linear clusters.  Is there a good method for transforming data like this?  I'm using python/pandas/numpy.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll want to try clustering the orange points. Some clustering methods will cope with the parallel clusters. I would probably start with [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html).

For more on clustering, check out [the tutorial on this scikit-learn page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html). Your situation is a bit like the 4th row here:

[image]

If you provide your data, I expect several people will take a look at it.